# EclipseLink can't retrieve entities inserted manually

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm having some trouble with EclipseLink. My program has to interact with a database (representing a building). I've written a little input-testmode where I can manually insert stuff through the console.

My problem: a normal getByID-operation works just fine if I try to retrieve an entity I previously inserted through EclipseLink itself (by commit()), but throws a NoResultException when trying to select a row manually inserted via SQL-script (building -> lots of rooms -> script).

This (oversemplified) works fine:

```
main() {
  MyRoom r = new MyRoom();
  r.setID("floor1-roomnr4");
  em.commit(r); //entity manager
  DAO.getRoomByID("floor1-roomnr4"); // works
}
```

and the combination of generation-script + simply getRoomByID() throws an exception.

If I try it in SQL Developer I get the result I want for the *exact* select statement which just threw a NoResultException. I also only get this problem in the input-mode, otherwise selecting the generated rows works also fine.

Does EclipseLink have some cache-mechanism I'm unaware of which is causing some problem?

Comment: Can you post some of the generation-script and the SQL generated by EclipseLink?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure EclipseLink and SQL Developer are connected to the same Database?  Please verify the connection information for both.  Is the generation-script committing the changes with the "commit" command?

Comment: Yes, the database is the same. The script is a SQL-script with standard insert-statements for all entries.

Answer (score 0):

If EclipseLink works similarly to Hibernate then yes there is a cache. The "first level cache" guaranties that you get the exact same instance within one transaction which makes sense. If you know EclipseLink/transactions then try to evict all loaded instances or commit the transaction and then try your DAO again. This would force EclipseLink to fetch the data from the database again

See [Answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472819/jpa-eclipselink-cache-life-span/3474595#3474595)